# Determining invariant probability measure and calculating $\lim_{n}p_{ij}^{(n)}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, markov-chains

> > Consider the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ with state space $E=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ and transition matrix
> >     $$
> > P=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1\\1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
> > $$
> >     (i) Does an invariant probability measure $\pi$ exist? If yes, then determine $\pi$. (2) Does $p_{ij}^{(n)}$ converge for $i,j\in E$ as $n\to\infty$? If yes, then determine $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_{ij}^{(n)}$ for $i,j\in E$. Do not use the convergence theorem for this part!

(i) $P$ is irreduccible, that is, there is only one communicating class $C=E$. $C$ is closed and finite, so it is positive recurrent. From this it follows that $C$ carries an invariant probability measure $\pi$. In order to determine $\pi$ I solved
$$
(x,y,z)\cdot P=(x,y,z)\text{ with }x+y+z=1,
$$
getting $\pi=(x,y,z)=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$.

(2) From the convergence theorem and (1) I know that it has to be
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}p_{ij}^{(n)}=\pi_j=\frac{1}{3}.
$$
But the task is to get this **without** the convergence theorem.

How can this be done?

For example for $i=1, j=2$, it is - as far as I see -

$$
p_{12}^{(2)}=\frac{1}{2^2},~~~~~p_{12}^{(3)}=3\cdot\frac{1}{2^3},~~~~~p_{12}^{(4)}=6\cdot \frac{1}{2^4},~~~~~p_{12}^{(5)}=9\cdot\frac{1}{2^5}
$$

Comment: Perron Frobenius is about diagonalizing the matrix and calculating the $n$-th power. So when you use the convergence theorem above you are not using Perron Frobenius, so it should be ok. Moreover, for part 1) note that the matrix is doubly stochastic and therefore (you have perhaps a proposition in your script) it is immediate that the stationary distribution is the uniform distribution over $S=\{1,2,3\}$, i.e. $\frac13,\frac13,\frac13$ as you correctly have.

Comment: @Stef I thought that maybe Perron-Frobenius is used in the proof of the mentioned convergence theorem so that I cannot use it.

Comment: I do not have a proof right in front of me, but a quick web search states that this is not necessarily so. This result can also be proved with the technique of coupling (if I had my Kulkarni book next to me - which unfortunately I do not - I could confirm/reject if there exists a proof that uses Perron-Frobenius). I think your teacher said no Perron-Frobenius to keep you from making endless calculations. I think he wants that you indeed use some convergence theorem to conclude immediately without having to calculate $P^(n)$ explicitly.

Comment: @Stef Thank you! To make sure that I am allowed to use the convergence theorem I will ask the tutor. Thank you for now. :D

Comment: Ok, you are welcome! But keep an eye here, because perhaps someone else can provide you with an answer that does not use the convergence theorem, as you want ;)!

Comment: @Stef Unfortunately, it is NOT allowed to use the convergence theorem.

Comment: Ok no problem, good that your tutor responded in the weekend that you shall not use the convergence theorem! You also got a great answer that "does not use" the perron-frobenius theory as the proof of the convergence apparently does! So everything is okay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks to compute $P^n$ for every $n$, where $$2P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{pmatrix}=3J-I,\qquad 3J=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ *This is pure algebra, only, playing with $3\times3$ matrices in the ring $\mathbb R[J]$.*

Note (and this will be the only matrix computation we shall need) that $$9J^2=(3J)^2=\begin{pmatrix}3&3&3\\3&3&3\\3&3&3\end{pmatrix}=3(3J),$$ hence,

> $$\forall n\geqslant1,\qquad J^n=J.$$

For every real parameter $x$, the power series expansion of the exponential yields
$$\mathrm e^{xJ}=I+\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{x^n}{n!}J=I+(\mathrm e^{x}-1)J.$$
As a consequence,
$$\mathrm e^{2xP}=\mathrm e^{x(3J-I)}=\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm e^{3xJ}=\mathrm e^{-x}I+(\mathrm e^{2x}-\mathrm e^{-x})J.$$
Identifying the coefficients of each $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ from both sides yields, for every $n\geqslant0$, $$2^n\,P^n=(-1)^nI+\left(2^n-(-1)^n\right)J,$$
 that is, $$P^n=J+z^n\,(I-J),\qquad z=-\frac12.$$
Thus, $$p_{ii}^{(n)}=\frac{1+2z^n}3,\qquad p_{ij}^{(n)}=\frac{1-z^n}3\quad (i\ne j).$$
This approach can be generalized to every dimension $d+1\geqslant2$, yielding $$p_{ii}^{(n)}=\frac{1+d\,z^n}{d+1},\qquad p_{ij}^{(n)}=\frac{1-z^n}{d+1}\quad (i\ne j),\qquad z=-\frac1d.$$

Comment: Wow, great.. that is a really great answer. Thank you very much! I tried to solve it by combinatorical thoughts - but that is not as half as nice...

Comment: Well... thanks.